# jsPDF create PDF from .html and open in new window

Tags: html, pdf, window, pdf-generation, jspdf

I am trying to use jsPDF to convert a .html file to PDF and open it in a new window.

I am gnerating de PDF like this:

```
function PDFFromHTML() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();

    // We'll make our own renderer to skip this editor
    var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#editor': function(element, renderer){
                    return true;
            }
    };

    // All units are in the set measurement for the document
    // This can be changed to "pt" (points), "mm" (Default), "cm", "in"
    doc.fromHTML('ticket.html', 15, 15, {
            'width': 170, 
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
}
```

I need something like window.open to open this pdf file in a new window but i can't find the way of doing it.

Regards,

Comment: i am realizing that doc.fromHTML('ticket.html' does not work neither...this jsPDF is quite hard to use..i just need to convert my .html to PDF and open it in a new window

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell, there isn't much documentation on the APIs other than looking directly at the [codes](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/jspdf.js) and existing [examples](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/tree/master/examples).

I am able to get the PDF file to open in a new window by adding a call to the `output` API after `doc.fromHTML(..)`, specifying the `dataurlnewwindow` argument like this:

```
doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
```

As to why `doc.fromHTML('ticket.html')` doesn't work, again referring to the [code](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/examples/js/basic.js#L316), the `source` argument needs to be:

> either a HTML-formatted string, or a reference to an actual DOM element.

So you may have to use the jquery [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) method to load in the content of `ticket.html`. Essentially, something that looks like:

```
$.get('ticket.html', function(content){
    doc.fromHTML(content), 15, 15, {'width': 170, 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers});
    doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
}, 'html');
```

Comment: helped me to load the ticket.html properly but i still don't know how to open that doc object as PDF in a new window

Comment: To open the doc object in a new window, just add `doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');` to your codes; after `doc.fromHTML()`.

Comment: mmmm..that opens a blank PDF with the word "undefined" in the middle of the blank PDF...i think that $('#ticket-content').load('ticket.html'); is not doing it's job...

Comment: The key to remember here is that `$.load()` (and `$.get()`) are asynchronous AJAX calls. To simplify things, I have updated my answer to use [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), and move the codes to open the new window to the callback function. This will ensure that the new window is opened **AFTER** the `ticket.html` is loaded.

Comment: mm great job but i am still getting a blank PDF, although now i am not seeing any undefined. As far as i understand, this JS codes the html into a base64 URL and opens it in a new tab. The problem now is that my html needs a longer base64 string than the maximum permitted in the URL, so now i am getting this errors in JS console: jsPDF PubSub Error Maximum call stack size exceeded RangeError, 
jsPDF Warning: rendering issues? provide a callback to fromHTML!

Comment: well im not sue if that's the problem cause if i doc.save('ticket.pdf'); instead of doc.output('dataurlnewwindow'); i am also saving a blank PDF.

Comment: Not sure it will make a difference, what browser are you using? Can you try with FF if you haven't?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. My codes work without any problems on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/dj1rvc9c/) with FF. With Chrome, the PDF will only render properly if I copied-and-paste the URL to another tab even after I disable Chrome default PDF Viewer plugin, and enable only the Adobe Reader plugin.

Comment: Ok man thanks for your time. I will try other solutions and see if i finally get it