# Only view PDF file online

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I have a link on my site to a pdf I'd like visitors to be able to view - but when clicked on, it has to be downloaded to be opened.

How can I get around this?

Ideally, I want to make it as easy as possible for potential clients - when they click on the link - it opens another tab/window with the pdf open.

```
 var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
    // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
    source = $('#customers')[0];

    // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
    // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
    // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
    // (class, of compound) at this time.
    specialElementHandlers = {
        // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 522
    };
    // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
    // 'inches' in this case
    pdf.fromHTML(
    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { // y coord
        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },

    function (dispose) {
        // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
        //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');
    }, margins);
```

And link of that code is in this jsfiddle file is here.

http://jsfiddle.net/xzZ7n/4861/

Comment: It's working flawless for me, try to clear your cache.

Comment: `pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');` will work. But jsFiddle has some security restriction. Try it in your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jsPDF create PDF from .html and open in new window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26221041/jspdf-create-pdf-from-html-and-open-in-new-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one  `doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');`.

instead of   `pdf.save('Test.pdf');`